# ImageView/Shape Drawable not rotating in landscape

Tags: android, rotation, imageview, android-shapedrawable

I'm using an image view with its source pointing to a shape drawable for the background for my app. I want it to look like this which is in the layout preview (blue on the top, orange on the bottom). [image]

However, whenever I run it, it looks like this. It's basically the portrait version, so it isn't being rotated. I use android:screenOrientation="landscape" in activity tag in the manifest to force it into landscape.[image]

This is the code for the image view in my layout, as well as the src

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:importantForAccessibility="no"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/background" />

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:centerColor="@color/light_blue_background"
        android:endColor="@color/orange_background"
        android:startColor="@color/teal_background" />
    <size android:height="16dp" />
    <size android:width="32dp" />
</shape>
```

I've tried to use the rotate attribute in the layout to set it to 90 degrees, but it doesn't come out quite as well.[image]

Anyone know how to try to get my background looking like it's supposed to in the preview?

Comment: insted of this  app:srcCompat="@drawable/background"  use android:background=""

Comment: That still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to manually adjust the gradient angle in the shape drawable XML itself. Set angle to 90, swap start and end gradient colours.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:importantForAccessibility="no"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:background="@drawable/background" />


<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
    android:centerColor="@color/light_blue_background"
    android:endColor="@color/orange_background"
    android:startColor="@color/teal_background" />

  </shape>
```